# What is `@stringfilter` in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-templates, frontend, django-template-filters

I sometimes see `@stringfilter` with [@register.filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/custom-template-tags/#django.template.Library.filter).

So, I created `test` filter with `@stringfilter` as shown below:

```py
# "templatetags/custom_tags.py"

from django.template import Library
from django.template.defaultfilters import stringfilter

register = Library()

@register.filter(name="test")
@stringfilter # Here
def test_filter(num1, num2):
    return
```

But, it accepted `int` type values without error as shown below:

```
# "templates/index.html"

{% load custom_tags %}

{{ 3|test:7 }} # Here
```

I thought that `@stringfilter` only accepts `str` type values giving error for the other types.

So, what is `@stringfilter` in Django?

Answer (score 0):

[@stringfilter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/custom-template-tags/#django.template.defaultfilters.stringfilter) can convert the 1st argument(parameter) to `str` type.

[The doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/custom-template-tags/#template-filters-that-expect-strings) says below about `@stringfilter`:

> If you’re writing a template filter that only expects a string as the
> first argument, you should use the decorator stringfilter. This will
> convert an object to its string value before being passed to your
> function

For example, pass the 1st argument `3` and the 2nd argument `7` to `test` filter as shown below:

```
# "templates/index.html"

{% load custom_tags %}

{{ 3|test:7 }} # Here
```

Then, only the 1st parameter `num1` is `str` type as shown below:

```py
# "templatetags/custom_tags.py"

@register.filter(name="test")
@stringfilter # Here
def test_filter(num1, num2):
    print(type(num1), type(num2)) # <class 'str'> <class 'int'>
    return
```

Be careful, if the order of `@stringfilter` and [@register.filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/custom-template-tags/#django.template.Library.filter) is opposite, the 1st parameter is not converted to `str` type as shown below:

```py
# "templatetags/custom_tags.py"

@stringfilter # Here
@register.filter(name="test") # Here
def test_filter(num1, num2):
    print(type(num1), type(num2)) # <class 'int'> <class 'int'>
    return
```

In addition, you can use `@stringfilter` with [@register.simple_tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/custom-template-tags/#django.template.Library.simple_tag), [@register.tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/custom-template-tags/#registering-the-tag) or [@register.inclusion_tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/custom-template-tags/#django.template.Library.inclusion_tag) as shown below. *If the order of `@stringfilter` and `@register.simple_tag`, `@register.tag` or `@register.inclusion_tag` is opposite, the 1st parameter is not converted to `str` type:

```py
# "templatetags/custom_tags.py"

@register.simple_tag(name="test")
@stringfilter
def test_tag(num1, num2):
    print(type(num1), type(num2)) # <class 'str'> <class 'int'>
    return
```

```py
# "templatetags/custom_tags.py"

@register.tag(name="test")
@stringfilter
def test_tag(parser, token):
    print(type(parser), type(token)) # <class 'str'> <class 'django.template.base.Token'>
    return PersonNode()

class PersonNode(Node):
    def render(self, context):
        return ""
```

```py
# "templatetags/custom_tags.py"

@register.inclusion_tag(name='test', filename='result.html')
@stringfilter
def test_tag(num1, num2):
    print(type(num1), type(num2)) # <class 'str'> <class 'int'>
    return
```